# Powershell export csv results to multiple sheets in an excel workbook

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I run a lot of scans against our AD looking for deficiencies (i.e. users without an email, user ID blank, on-leave but AD account not disabled, etc) and all my results are exported to csv files. I'd like each csv result stored on a sheet in a single excel workbook. I've found a lot of sites showing how to convert a csv to an xls or how to export to a single xls sheet but I can't find anything else meeting my needs. I don't have the ability to import the Import-Excel / Export-Excel modules from the PS gallery. Any suggestions on how I can export 3 CSV files (actually array objects - not sure they need to be exported to CSV first) to three sheets in a workbook?

What I've found so far:

```
# Create Excel object
$excel = new-object -comobject Excel.Application
# Create a new workbook
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.add()
# Name a worksheet
$workbook.WorkSheets.Item(1).Name = "Users"
# Add data from a csv to the current sheet
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.add(“C:\export_users.csv”)
```

What I can't figure out is how to add data from additional csv files onto additional sheets in the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Add another worksheet with another Add().

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$wb1 = $excel.workbooks.add()
$wb1.WorkSheets.Item(1).Name = 'Users 1'
$wb1.Worksheets.Item(1).Name
$wb1.Worksheets.Count
$wb1.Worksheets.Add() | Out-Null
$wb1.WorkSheets.Item(2).Name = 'Users 2'
$wb1.Worksheets.Item(2).Name
$wb1.Worksheets.Count
```

I have had some success using the `ImportExcel` module for PowerShell.

Comment: I don't have the ability to import the Import-Excel / Export-Excel modules from the PS gallery.

Comment: This answer does not use the `ImportExcel` module. Did you try this code? What was the result?